# SQL query for the most updated version in the table

Tags: sql, oracle

Need a oracle sql query to get the latest updated version. I have a sql table which is having the below columns, Application & Version Id.

In the below example I have different version ids for an Application ABC and their corresponding sub versions. I need to retrieve latest subversion for a version id.
For example, for Version id 1, I don't have any subversions so the VersionId =1 will be the latest one and need to pull this record. Similarly under version id 2, I have two sub versions 2.1 and 2.2. Under 2.1, there is no further subversions, so 2.1 would be the latest version and need to pull this. Again under 2.2 we have 2.2.1 and again under 2.2.1, we have 2.2.1.1 as the latest version and need to fetch this record. Likewise I need to get all the below mentioned latest subversions from the table using a Oracle SQL query.

**For example:**

```
Application |  Version Id   
:-----------|-------------:  
ABC         | 1 (latest in Version 1)  
ABC         |   2   
ABC         |   2.1 (latest in version 2.1)  
ABC         |   2.2   
ABC         |   2.2.1   
ABC         |   2.2.1.1 (latest in version 2.2.1)  
ABC         |   2.2.2       
ABC         |   2.2.2.1     
ABC         |   2.2.2.1.1 (latest in version 2.2.2.1)    
ABC         |   2.2.2.2 (latest in version 2.2.2.2)    
ABC         |   2.3 (latest in version 2.3)    
ABC         |   2.4   
ABC         |   2.4.1 (latest in version 2.4)  
ABC         |   2.5   
ABC         |   2.5.1 (latest in version 2.4)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
with data (application, version) as
(
select 'ABC', '1'  from dual
union all select 'ABC', '2' from dual
union all select 'ABC', '2.1' from dual
union all select 'ABC', '2.2' from dual
union all select 'ABC', '2.2.1' from dual
union all select 'ABC', '2.2.1.1' from dual
union all select 'ABC', '2.2.2' from dual
union all select 'ABC', '2.2.2.1' from dual
union all select 'ABC', '2.2.2.1.1' from dual
union all select 'ABC', '2.2.2.2' from dual
union all select 'ABC', '2.3' from dual
union all select 'ABC', '2.4' from dual
union all select 'ABC', '2.4.1' from dual
union all select 'ABC', '2.5' from dual
union all select 'ABC', '2.5.1' from dual
)
select * from data d1
where not exists (select null
                    from data d2
                   where d2.application = d1.application
                     and d2.version like d1.version||'.%')
order by application, version;
```